# Fundamental group of the double torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

In May's "A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology" I am supposed to calculate the fundamental group of the double torus. Can this be done using van Kampen's theorem and the fact that for (based) spaces $X, Y$: $\pi_1(X\times Y) = \pi_1(X)\times\pi_1(Y)$? Or do I need other theorems to prove this?

I believe that this should equal $\pi_1(T)\times\pi_1(T)\times\pi_1(S^1)$ where $T$ is the torus minus a closed disc on the surface, but I do not know how to calculate $\pi_1(T)$.

Answer (score 17):

By van Kampen's theorem, what you get is actually
$$\pi_1(T)\ast_{\pi_i(S^1)}\pi_1(T)$$
which is an amalgamated product (a pushout in the category of groups).
Roughly speaking if you have two groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ and
embeddings $i_1$ and $i_2$ of a group $H$ in both then $G_1\ast_H\ast G_2$
is the group freely generated by the elements of $G_1$ and $G_2$
but identifying elements $i_1(h)$ and $i_2(h)$ for $h\in H$.

Now $\pi_1(T)$ can be computed using the fact that $T$ deformation retracts
to a bouquet of two circles. (Think about the standard torus; fix a point
and look at the circles through it going round the torus in the two natural
ways.)

Comment: "$T$ deformation retracts to a bouquet of two circles" -- you mean, $T$ minus a point(or disc) deformation retracts to a bouquet of two circles?

Comment: I meant exactly what I said: see Ringo's definition of $T$.

Answer (score 10):

Hi: Please see [this link](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/algebraic_topology/Math205B_Mar02.pdf), exercise 0.2 in the pdf file written by Christopher Walker in March 2, 2007 for Math 205B - Topology class. This has a nice explanation as well as some more information.

Comment: Doesn't this answer your question?

Comment: -1: A merely related link is not an answer to a specific question. You could as well point to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert%E2%80%93van_Kampen_theorem#Examples).

Comment: However, if the original answer had included the magic words "see Exercise 0.2", this would be a perfectly fine answer. (Note for those who don't follow the link: Baez gives the *solution* there. I don't think it makes sense to just give a link to where somebody has *asked* a question.)

Comment: @Michael Lugo: I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

As a futher hint: the fundamental group of the torus $\mathbb{T}$ is generated by $a, b$ and has the relation $abAB$, where capitals denote inverses.  If you remove an open disk then you get a once-holed torus $T$.  Now the fundamental group is free (why?) and the boundary is the homotopic to the element $abAB$ (why?).

So you can take another copy of the torus, say $\mathbb{S}$, with fundamental group generated by $c, d$ and having relation $cdCD$.  Again remove a disk to get a once holed torus $S$. Now carefully follow the answer already given, gluing $T$ and $S$, and so on.